# htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given ..

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

my form code:

```
<p>{!!Form::open(array("","id"=>"form"))!!}</p>
<p>Initial barcode :&nbsp </p>
<p>{!! Form::text('initialbarcode',array("id"=>"initialbarcode"))!!}</p>
<p>Barcode3 :&nbsp </p>
<p>{!! Form::text('barcode3',array("id"=>"barcode3"))!!}</p>
<p>Quantity :&nbsp </p>
<p>{!! Form::text('qty',array("id"=>"qty"))!!}</p>
<p>Kgs :&nbsp </p>
<p>{!! Form::text('kgs',array("id"=>"kgs"))!!}</p>
<p>Price :&nbsp </p>
<p>{!! Form::text('price',array("id"=>"price"))!!}</p>
<p>{!! Form::text('name',array("id"=>"name"))!!}</p>
<p><select name="category" id="category"></p>
@foreach($options as $option)
<option>{{$option->category}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
<p>{!! Form::close()!!}</p>
```

Here this code returns following error : 
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Users\Toshiba\farmzop\resources\views\nonfz\nonfz.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

Please note the signature of the `Form::text` method:

```
/**
* Create a text input field.
*
* @param  string $name
* @param  string $value
* @param  array  $options
*
* @return string
*/
public function text($name, $value = null, $options = [])
```

Just change:

```
{!! Form::text('initialbarcode',array("id"=>"initialbarcode"))!!}
```

to

```
{!! Form::text('initialbarcode', null, ["id"=>"initialbarcode"]) !!}
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please close the question.